# Expert iptables Nat - Virtual interface ip address issue

Tags: iptables, nat, forwarding, interface

I've been looking information related to this problem several days, I had no luck finding a concrete explanation.

Explanation about this issue:
With this command I redirect one ip to another ip in other server.

- Server A = 169.200.77.211
- Server B = 155.155.51.15

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 169.200.77.211 -j DNAT --to-destination 155.155.51.15 && iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE && echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

All work very well, but when I add in server B the ip from server A NAT forwarding not work.

Example:
In server B, I go to `/etc/ips` I add ip server A :
`169.200.77.211:255.255.255.0:169.200.77.255`

In server B all policies default is ACCEPT, there is not rules (this is for testing purposes)

**More information:**
In a control panel such as cPanel or DirectAdmin, you have to add  IP via virtual interface o panel control, when I added the ip server A (nat forwarding) to a domain, Nat forwarding not work.

¿what is the cause this happening ?

Help is really appreciated!!!!! Thank you in advance

Comment: "when I add in server B the ip from server A": why are you doing that?

Comment: why, if I not add this, I can't add the ip of Server A a domain in server B

Comment: did you `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` ??

Comment: I'm sorry, but based on your text and comment, I really am NOT able to understand your problem: please consider rephrasing it while adding info about "the problem" and not only about your hypothetical solution.